# SlideToggle dropdown menue in twitterbootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create a dropdown menu using twitter bootstrap, now I want that it will slide like this [Link](http://adminex.themebucket.net/) or [Link](http://avalon.redteamux.com/index.html#).
my html is

```
  <div class="col-md-2 sidebar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="top_space">

      <div class="dropdown">
          <ul class="nav">
              <li class="dropdown nav"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu nav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>

      </div>
    <hr class="hrc"/>
    <br class="dropdown-difference"/>
    <div class="dropdown">

        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown nav" id="slide"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu nav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li> <hr class="hrc"/>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li><span class="divider"></span>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

in the mention link's look at the sidebar, when someone click on the main/head/parent menu then the child will slide down but does not effect any other element...

But in my case it will slide on the second dropdown and effect it's child element.....
For full code and result click on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/msz900/wbntcjcj/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in fact is not bootstrap dropdown plugin, but the [accordion plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). So this means that if you want to build something like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/sjmtpajc/show/), just check the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/sjmtpajc/) and note that you don't need to use `!important` as much as i used in my css file because if you load your css after bootstrap.css file, you will override it.

```
<br>
<div class="col col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Layouts
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href="#"> Blank Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Boxed Page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Sidebar Collapsed</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Horizontal Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        UI Elements
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href="#"> General</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Buttons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Tabs &amp; Accordions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Typography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Slider</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Panels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Widgets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        Components
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href="#"> Grids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Media Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Tree View</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Nestable</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.panel {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
}

.panel-body {
    padding: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
}

.panel-heading {
    padding: 0; 
    background: #424f63 !important;
    color: #fff !important;    
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
}

.panel-heading:hover {
    background: #353f4f !important;
    color: #65cea7 !important;
}

.panel-heading h4 a{
    padding: 12px 20px;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}

.panel-heading h4 a:active, .panel-heading h4 a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}    

.panel-heading h4 a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu-list {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #353f4f;
    display: none;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sub-menu-list > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 50px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
```

And the javascript code:

```
$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).find("a").find('span.glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');   
  $(this).find("a:not(.collapsed)").find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');   
})

$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).find("a:not(.collapsed)").find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');  
})
```

In case you want to change the icons you can easly do by select the ones you like from [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs). This icons comes along with bootstrap so you can use them for free but don't forget to change the javascript code with the new icons classes.

In case you wonder what does this javascript do, just check [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) section `events`, this two events fires immediately after you open and close the tabs.

Comment: can you please add the angle(caret) with this code, like when I click the menu then the caret sign change to downward else it sign remain the same as upward..

Comment: The width of the panl and sub-menu will also not going to 100% I tried a lot and still trying can you please check it...

Comment: I've updated my answer, i've added the caret icons, check it now, i think you will like that.

Comment: there is a little bit JavaScript confliction, by the way thanks', I will handle it from here....

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/rurnff1y/)**

Below is the approach

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav .dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).dropdown('toggle')
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    e.relatedTarget.stop(1).slideDown();
  }).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(1).slideUp()
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 1200px;
  float: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: #59646E;
}
.top_space {
  margin-top: 56px;
}
.sidebar .dropdown li {
  width: 100%;
  background: #282828;
  color: #000;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: silver !important;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  color: #255 !important;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: gray !important;
  border-left: 5px solid #59646E;
  border-right: 5px solid #282828;
}
.sidebar .dropdown li {
  border-left: 5px solid #59646E;
}
.sidebar .dropdown ul li:hover {
  border-left: 5px solid #012773;
}
.sidebar .dropdown li ul {
  width: 100%;
  background: #222222;
}
.sidebar .nav {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-difference {
  margin-top: -18px;
}
.hrc {
  background: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 sidebar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="top_space">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown nav"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu nav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr class="hrc" />
    <br class="dropdown-difference" />
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown nav" id="slide"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu nav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```